# ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Rating'

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook

I want to add a graph to my file and it shows the following error and prints an empty graph. I want to plot a graph between the rating column that has values (1,2,3,4,5) and the number of rows in each rating.
This is the code:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(6,6)})
plt.title('Distribution of Ratings')
sns.countplot(x = 'Rating', Edata = Edata);
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-32533aad2dd0> in <module>
  1 sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(6,6)})
  2 plt.title('Distribution of Ratings')
----> 3 sns.countplot(x = 'Rating', Edata = Edata);

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in countplot(x, y, hue, 
data, order, hue_order, orient, color, palette, saturation, dodge, ax, **kwargs)
3553                           estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed,
3554                           orient, color, palette, saturation,
-> 3555                           errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
3556 
3557     plotter.value_label = "count"

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, 
hue, data, order, hue_order, estimator, ci, n_boot, units, seed, orient, color, palette, 
saturation, errcolor, errwidth, capsize, dodge)
1613         """Initialize the plotter."""
1614         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient,
-> 1615                                  order, hue_order, units)
1616         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
1617         self.estimate_statistic(estimator, ci, n_boot, seed)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/categorical.py in 
establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
 150                 if isinstance(var, str):
 151                     err = "Could not interpret input '{}'".format(var)
--> 152                     raise ValueError(err)
 153 
 154             # Figure out the plotting orientation

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Rating'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should pass data parameter instead of edata

```
sns.countplot(x='Rating', data=Edata);
```