# ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Survived'

Tags: python, seaborn

Attribute od dataset:

```
    Index(['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp',
               'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked'],
              dtype='object')
```

To plot Count Plot using Seaborn library.

```
    sns.set_style('whitegrid')
    sns.countplot(x='Survived',df=data)
```

Error:
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Survived'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Rating'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61713669/valueerror-could-not-interpret-input-rating)

Comment: `sns.countplot(x='Survived', data=df)`... switch `data` and `df` around. Fundamentally though, make sure that you understand how parameters and arguments work in python. You tried to pass `df` as a parameter and `data` as an argument. I know what you are trying to do, but you are telling python that `df` is a parameter of `seaborn.countplot` when it isn't -- that is your dataframe that you are passing to the parameter~ Please see the docs for a list of parameters... or press CTRL + Shift in  your jupyter notebook... https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this `sns.countplot(x=df.Survived)`